# how to detect scrollPosition with fireEvent.scroll? - React-testing-library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, scroll, react-testing-library

*[For question purpose, I make dummy example to make it easier to understand]*

Let's say I have this homepage component that will toggle color when reach 1/3 of page height.

```
// Homepage.js
const Home = (props) => {
  const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll)

    return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll)
  }, [toggle])

  const handleScroll = () => {
    const scrollPosition = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    const oneThirdPageHeight = (1 / 3) * document.documentElement.offsetHeight;

    if (scrollPosition > onethirdPageHeight) {
      return setToggle(true)
    }
    return setToggle(false)
  }

  return <div style={{ height: '1500px', color: toggle ? 'blue' : 'red'}}>hello</div>
}
```

and for the test file

```
// Homepage.test.js
test('should toggle color when scrolled', () => {
  const { getByText } = render(<Homepage />);
  const DivEl = getByText('hello');

  expect(DivEl).toHaveStyle('color: red');
  fireEvent.scroll(window, { target: { scrollY: 800 } });
  expect(DivEl).toHaveStyle('color: blue'); // --> failing
});
```

It seems like I can't make the DOM scrolled by doing `fireEvent.scroll(window, { target: { scrollY: 800 } })`. Where did I miss? Please help, thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you had any luck in scrolling?

Answer (score 0):

- 1- first you can create a div/section with a fixed height and then set its overflow property to scroll.
- 2- add some content to the div and scroll it programmatically using the scrollTop property.
- 3- you can fire a scroll event on the div/section and check the scrollTop value